# Why is a vector function not smooth if $r'=0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, curves

It is stated that a vector function is smooth if its derivative is continuous and nowhere zero, but I can’t find a proof or a geometric interpretation. Is this a definition or a theorem?

Comment: It's like you walk, stop, and (probably turn and) walk again. There will a singularity in the route.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect the source of your statement is sloppy or misquoted; not knowing the source, I can't tell which one. Usually, a **function** is called smooth if it has a continuous derivative (of 1st order... or of all orders, in other people's usage). A **curve** is smooth if it's parametrized by a  smooth function whose derivative is nowhere zero.

For example, $\vec r(t) = (t-\sin t, 1-\cos t)$ is a smooth function but it does not describe a smooth curve: the image is the [cycloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid).

[image: cycloid]

The cusps become possible when $\vec r{}'(t)$ turns to zero; this is why the definition of a smooth curve prohibits $\vec r{}'(t)=0$.

Here is a sketch of the proof that $\vec r{}'(t)\ne 0$ implies smoothness in some geometric meaning. Given $t_0$, pick an index $j$ such that the $j$th component of the velocity vector is nonzero at $t_0$. Then it's also nonzero in a neighborhood of $t_0$. By the inverse function theorem the function $t\mapsto x_j(t)$ is invertible. Let its inverse be $t=f(x_j)$. Then $x_j\mapsto \vec r(f(x_j))$ is a non-parametric equation of the curve, which expresses coordinates $x_i$, $i\ne j$, as smooth functions of $x_j$. Such a curve has tangent line given by a familiar equation.

Comment: You are right, I meant a smooth curve described by a vector function. You say that the cusps of the cycloid "become possible..." but I am asking the reverse: why are the cusps impossible if r'(t) is not zero? I think it has something to do with the fact that a vector cannot change direction "abruptly" unless it vanishes. Is that fact a definition or a theorem? On another note, how did you manage to put an arrow on top of the r? Thanks for answering.

Comment: @user106218 Actually, you are asking both things: look at the title of your question. I added a sketch to the end of the post; for details, see a textbook dealing with geometry of curves. The arrow is `\vec r`.

Comment: @user106218 The arrow on top of $r$ is rendered via MathJax on this site. Basically, you put your $\LaTeX$ code between two dollar signs, so $\vec r$ will be entered as `$\vec r$`. See [FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/117/64206) for further info.

Comment: There is indeed a physical interpretation on Thomas' Calculus, page 910:
"...the derivative dr/dt is just what we want for modeling a particle's velocity. It points in the direction of motion and gives the rate of change of position with respect of time. For a smooth curve, the velocity is never zero; the particle does not stop or reverse direction."

Comment: By the way, comparing just this page with Stewart's books in general, I like Thomas better. Stewart tries to be concise, I suppose for the sake of of efficiency. Elegant and precise sentences that use a minimum of words, although appropriate and even insisted upon in academic papers are not necessarily the best for teaching math.

Answer (score 0):

This is a definition. See for example [page $910$ of Thomas' Calculus](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ma5sAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA910&lpg=PA910&dq=vector+function+is+smooth+if+derivative+is+continuous&source=bl&ots=6NTOAEk2YO&sig=N-B2UxtbhvAFqiE9B0siZgPlSDI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vOcQVMmZF-_EiwKPxYGYAQ&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=vector%20function%20is%20smooth%20if%20derivative%20is%20continuous&f=false), which also gives a geometric interpretation of a smooth vector function.